# Default month in Ajax CalendarExtender in asp.net

Tags: .net

I have two textboxes named "CheckIn Date" and "CheckOut Date" having CalenderExtender Bind.

I want to set the default month display in "CheckOut Date" on TextChange of "CheckIn Date".

And on "CheckOut" TextChange event I am calculating days between this two textboxes.

Plz Help me.......

Answer (score 0):

Assign CalenderExtende's SelectedDate property to date you want Calender to show.